# Update two tables at the same time using Laravel8

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have in my database the following two tables :

[image]

[image]

And I have the following form :

```
 <form id="contratform" method="post" action="contrats"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id_projet" />
             <div class="form-row">
             <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputAddress">Numéro de contrat</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero_contrat" name="numero_contrat" 
              placeholder="Numéro de contrat">
            </div>
             <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputState">Modele de contrat</label>
                <select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="id_modele_contrat">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                @foreach($modeles_contrat as $modele_contrat)
                     <option data-id="{{$modele_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}" value="{{$modele_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}">{{$modele_contrat->modele_contrat}}</option>
                @endforeach
                </select>
              </div>
          </div>
             <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="date_tournage">Date de signature</label>
                <div class="input-group date">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_signature" name="date_signature">
                  <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
                        <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                  </span> 
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="date_premiere_diffusion">Date de fin contrat</label>
                <div class="input-group date">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_fin_contrat" name="date_fin_contrat">
                    <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
                            <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                    </span> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="description">Lieu de signature</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lieu_signature" name="lieu_signature" 
              placeholder="Lieu de signature"/>
            </div>
             <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputAddress">Signataire Client</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="signataire_client" name="signataire_client" 
                  placeholder="Signataire">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputAddress">Qualité Signataire Client</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualite_signataire_client" name="qualite_signataire_client" 
                    placeholder="Qualite de Signataire">
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputAddress">Signataire Agence de conseil</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="signataire_agence_conseil" name="signataire_agence_conseil" 
                  placeholder="Signataire">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputAddress">Qualité Signataire Agence de conseil</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualite_signataire_agence_conseil" name="qualite_signataire_agence_conseil" 
                    placeholder="Qualite de Signataire">
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputAddress">Signataire Agence de production</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="signataire_agence_production" name="signataire_agence_production" 
                  placeholder="Signataire">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputAddress">Qualité Signataire Agence de production</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualite_signataire_agence_production" name="qualite_signataire_agence_production" 
                    placeholder="Qualite de Signataire">
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputAddress">Signataire Agence de casting</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="signataire_agence_casting" name="signataire_agence_casting" 
                  placeholder="Signataire">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputAddress">Qualité Signataire Agence de casting</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualite_signataire_agence_casting" name="qualite_signataire_agence_casting" 
                    placeholder="Qualite de Signataire">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date_tournage">Date de paiement</label>
                <div class="input-group date">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_paiement" name="date_paiement">
                  <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
                    <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                  </span> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center">
              <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
              <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" />
              <input type="submit" name="action_button" id="action_button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Enregistrer" />
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-6">
              <span id="form_result1"></span>
            </div>

          </form>
```

I want update on the first table all the inputs in the form , and update on the second table the last input in the form `date_paiement`.

I tried the followin code but doesn't work :

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
         
            $rules = array(
        
         'id_modele_contrat' => 'required',
         'date_signature' => 'required',
         'date_fin_contrat' => 'required',
         'lieu_signature' => 'required',
         'signataire_client' => 'required',
         'qualite_signataire_client' => 'required',
         'signataire_agence_conseil' => 'required',
          'qualite_signataire_agence_conseil' => 'required',
          'signataire_agence_production' => 'required',
          'qualite_signataire_agence_production' => 'required',
          'signataire_agence_casting' => 'required',
          'qualite_signataire_agence_casting' => 'required'
            );

            $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

            if($error->fails())
            {
                return response()->json(['errors' => $error->errors()->all()]);
            }
        

           $form_data = array(

             'id_modele_contrat'       =>   $request->id_modele_contrat,
             'date_signature'          =>   $request->date_signature,
             'date_fin_contrat'        =>   $request->date_fin_contrat,
             'lieu_signature'          =>   $request->lieu_signature,
             'signataire_client'       =>   $request->signataire_client,
             'qualite_signataire_client'        =>   $request->qualite_signataire_client,
             'signataire_agence_conseil'        =>   $request->signataire_agence_conseil,
             'qualite_signataire_agence_conseil'=>   $request->qualite_signataire_agence_conseil,
             'signataire_agence_production'     =>   $request->signataire_agence_production,
             'qualite_signataire_agence_production'     =>   $request->qualite_signataire_agence_production,
             'signataire_agence_casting'   =>   $request->signataire_agence_casting,
             'qualite_signataire_agence_casting'        =>   $request->qualite_signataire_agence_casting
        );

          $form_data2 = array(


             'date_paiement'        =>   $request->date_paiement

          );

      Contrat::where('id_contrat',$request->hidden_id)->update($form_data);

    Projet_Casting::where('id_contrat',$request->hidden_id)->update($form_data2);

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Data is successfully updated']);
    }
```

I'm trying to update the two tables at the same time .

How can I do that , what is wrong with my code ? When I execute my code I get no errors but doesn't modify the data .

If you have anu idea please help

Comment: Before using the `update` method, you will need to specify a fillable property on your model class. You did it? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Also your `<input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" />` does not have any value assigned, so your queries `where('id_contrat',$request->hidden_id)->update(...` may not correspond to any record

Comment: do this in  the top of your update method dd(Contrat::where('id_contrat',$request->hidden_id)->get());   , update your question with the result of dd

Comment: Thank you for your reply , yes I did it , but doesn't work

Comment: thank you , it works now  , it was because of the hidden_id , it was null

Answer (score 0):

I think hidden id don't have any value

```
`<input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id_projet" />`
```

and missing `{{ method_field('put') }}` after update form